# MinGW cc1plus.exe fatal error (file exists)

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw

I recently installed a new SSD on my machine, and when I did a clean install of windows I got Visual Studio Code, and was about to get the c++ extension up and running, so I got MinGW, and tried to install the GCC and G++ compilers... And low and behold, after trying a lot of solutions, it is still not working properly on this computer image.

When I try to test the compiler after I got MinGW installed properly, this is what it output:

```
gcc.exe -Wp,-v -E -xc -dD -x c++ nul
ignoring nonexistent directory 
"c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory 
"c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: nul: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Error: 1
```

The odd part is that the cc1plus.exe is in the MinGW directory, and I even added it to the include path later to see if that would help, and still nothing. I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

This bug has become the bane of my existence for the last week. If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate the help. I've had success with MinGW in the past, but for some reason it's giving me problems this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commandline is:

```
gcc.exe -Wp,-v -E -xc -dD -x c++ nul
```

The error:

```
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: nul: No such file or directory
```

is the C++ compiler (`cc1plus.exe`) telling you that the input file `nul`
does not exist. That will be because there is no file called `nul` in the current directory.

The Windows CMD `NUL` device is a virtual device to which the *output* of a command may be
*redirected* ( `command >NUL`) to throw it away. It is not a *file*.

If you want to test that the compiler can be successfully invoked with this commandline,
then write a program such as:

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Save it in the current directory and run:

```
gcc.exe -Wp,-v -E -xc -dD -x c++ main.cpp
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure the 'nul' argument used to test the compiler, or open it. That's what the Visual Studio Code extension I am trying to debug uses. It's the C++ tools extension from Microsoft. They use that line to force the first run of the compiler so that they can then run the language server. Do you know of any other reason it could be having this problem.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out... You were actually right. It was trying to pass the output to the NULL virtual device from Windows.... I didn't realize that windows had the "start" key defaulted to 4 for some reason??? So it didn't start. I flipped it to 1, and now everything is working properly. Thank you sir!!!

Answer (score -1):

Close your IDE and go your program folder and open folder with your IDE. Then run  and check to see if your problem is solved.